# how can I plot a "barplot" with each bar at different heights? in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I need to create a barplot, with this data:

```
a<-c(0.02686811,0.01724433,0.05678611,0.01328387,0.02083748,0.01340736)

b<-c(0.12310228,0.07907666,0.08608878,0.04961274,0.12348462,0.03520654)
```

that's easy:

```
rbind(a,b)->zz

barplot(zz)
```

However, and here is when it comes the difficult part, each element of the vectors "a" and "b" represents data taken in a different time:

```
t<-c(0,2,2,5,6,10)
```

I would like to represent the each bar of the barplot at different heights, each height represented by each time in vector "t".

So for example, the 1st bar in barplot(zz) I want it to begin at a height of 0 (the position of the lower edge of the rectangle being at height 0), the 2nd bar, I want it to start at a height of 2, and so on...

I hope you guys understood my problem, any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Tina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zz <-rbind(t,zz)
barplot(zz, col=c("white", "black", "grey") )
```